# Correct way to use AngularJS ng-class or alternatives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a project where I want to display multiple counts on different filtered results of the same array.
I do this with a binding which is inside an ng-repeat like so:

```
{{ (queue | filter: {doctorName:d.doctorName} | filter: {status:'Scheduled'}).length }}
```

Is there a way I can re-use that result, I would like to use the result in an ng-class but I can only do this by running the same query like so:

```
ng-class="(queue | filter: {doctorName:d.doctorName} | filter: {status:'Scheduled'}).length ? 'showHint' : 'hideHint'"
```

Is there an easier more efficient way to do this?

[Here is the JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7ea3bup2/1/)

Comment: If you upgrade your angular version you can use the `variable in expression as alias_expression` syntax. `alias_expression` can then be used for in `ng-class` without repeating the filter expression. [see the manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 1):

The easier way would be to do like @origonof suggests.

However if you want to only do the calculation once for each doctor you could use the Controller as syntax.

I have modified your example http://jsfiddle.net/krausekjaer/4yfwckzv/7/

Here is the controller I added:

```
docApp.controller('DocterController', function ($scope, $filter) {
   var self = this;
   self.docQueue = $filter('filter')($scope.queue, {doctorName: $scope.d.doctorName});  
});
```

and it can be used in the html like this

```
<div ng-controller="DocterController as docCtrl">
  <div>{{ d.doctorName }}</div>
  <div ng-class="(docCtrl.docQueue | filter: {status:'Scheduled'}).length ? 'showHint' : 'hideHint'">
    Bookings: {{ (docCtrl.docQueue | filter: {status:'Scheduled'}).length }}
  </div>
  <div ng-class="(docCtrl.docQueue | filter: {status:'Waiting'}).length ? 'showHint' : 'hideHint'">
    Queue: {{ (docCtrl.docQueue | filter: {status:'Waiting'}).length }}
  </div>
  <div ng-class="(docCtrl.docQueue | filter: {status:'Served'}).length ? 'showHint' : 'hideHint'">
    Active: {{ (docCtrl.docQueue | filter: {status:'Served'}).length }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Note I updated angular to a never version as well, the Controller as functionality should be present in 2.0 also if I remeber correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Move the filter from the view to the controller:

```
myApp.controller('myControllerNameCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.queue = ...;
  var firstFilter = $filter('firstFilter')(queue, {doctorName: d.doctorName});
  var secondFilter = ...;
  $scope.filteredQueue = secondFilter;
});
```